# google places - disable autocomplete

Tags: html, autocomplete

I am working with the google places autocomplete.
This works fine with this input field and some javascript:

```
<input type="text" name="customerAddress" placeholder="Address" autocomplete="off">
```

But: I would like to disable the autofill function of personal data.

For that I set autocomplete="off", but the filed will be fill via autofill.
(tested it with iPhone)

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately many modern browsers just ignore the autocomplete off.
You can use a little trick to still achieve this:
Use a random name, id and autocomplete value. For example:

```
<input name='forminput1' id='forminput1' autocomplete='forminput1'</input>
```

Just make sure you dont use a real word like address or email as a browser will recognize this and just autocomplete the field.